# No coding no CIVICRM? Or..?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

I run a small but growing non-profit and I was looking into CIVICRM as our much needed CRM system. Now I know no coding at all, can I still custumie and use CIVI or do I nedd to know coding?TY!!

Answer (score 4):

You can customize civicrm in many ways - eg [add custom data/fields](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/); you can also [add extensions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/introduction/extensions/) - essentially packages of code that help you leverage civicrm further. Lots of ways to customize your civicrm without requiring you to know touch code.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed customize CiviCRM in many ways, as KarinG explained. However, if you are a small NGO with small budgets I would recommend doing only the absolutely necessary customizations and stay away from 'i want this to look a little different'. Not because you can not, but because the benefits will probably not outweight the effort.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to customize the appearance and UI of CiviCRM as well.  See this talk from 2015's Denver conference: [CiviCON Denver- Make It Pretty: Customize the Appearance of CiviCRM without Knowing How to Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Fby5SWngUc)